# android how to remove edittext's HighlightColor

Tags: android

I made a drag and drop function for my EditText view. The code I am using is the same as the Google official tutorial.

When I drop something into the EditText, it always shows a highlight on the EditText. I have tried setting `drophelper.Options.Builder() setHighlightColor` to transparent, but the highlight area just changed color.

Does anyone know how to disable the drop highlight?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a bit different color which is transparent whte

```
android:textColorHighlight="#00FFFFFF"
```

Or this

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

and disable default highlighting

```
android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="false"


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="false"
        android:textColorHighlight="#00FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

##### Autofill Framework

The highlight could also bedue to Android's Autofill Framework more so if you could be using the `android:autofillHints` attribute. To override the highlight setting:

- SDK min version must be > 26
- In applications' theme `(style)` add **`android:autofilledHighlight`** and set the value to the color you want (to 'disable' this highlight just set it to transparent).

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  But there could be some misunderstanding in my question. https://developer.android.google.cn/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop  please check out this link, the highlight is the large purple area.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions above